# mysql_fetch_row not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which queries database and counts the number of rows in it.

```
if($action=='shipping_list')
{ 
    $row;
    $shipping=shipping_list();
    $numrow=$r[0];
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($paging);
    include('shipping_list.php');
}

function shipping_list()
{
    global $MEMS;
    global $row;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory
                      WHERE Yield >=330 AND 
                            (Q = 'Pass' OR Q = 'No Q') AND 
                            shipdate = ' '
                   ORDER BY Wafer ASC, RC ASC";
    $shipping = $MEMS -> query($query);

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) Inventory
               WHERE Yield >=330 AND 
                     (Q = 'Pass' OR Q = 'No Q') AND 
                     shipdate = ' '";
    $paging = $MEMS -> query($query);
    return $shipping;
}
```

Basically, it calls on the function, which has a SQL command that counts the number of queries returned. The code then fetches the row with MySQL fetch row.

However, `$row` keep returning `NULL`, does anyone here know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you use the query outside the function? What does `mysql_error()` return?

Comment: `$paging` is in the local scope of the function, so `$row=mysql_fetch_row($paging);` is never going to return a result.  You should organize the code better though so that you aren't relying on global variables to pass information.  You have a class use with `$MEMS`, and that would be an appropriate way to keep information stored.

Comment: Not sure why you would be surprised that it isn't working. It _is_ deprecated. :/ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: @Jordan Yes, it is deprecated, however, it is still supported in most versions but won't be in the future.  Just because something is deprecated doesn't instantly mean that's why it's not working.  Suggest moving to newer versions of PDO or something if you will, but don't assume an entire question invalid just because of the built-in functions that are being used.

Comment: Your second query is missing `FROM Inventory` was that a typo? `$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) Inventory`

Comment: 2 Month ago : Could my answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

- I suppose the function `shipping_list()` is in the `shipping_list.php` file.

If you want to call a function include the .php first not after the call

```
if($action=='shipping_list'){ 

   $shipping=shipping_list();
   $numrow=$r[0];
   $row=mysql_fetch_row($paging);
   include('shipping_list.php');
}
```

correct

```
if($action=='shipping_list'){ 
   include('shipping_list.php');
   $shipping=shipping_list();
   $numrow=$r[0];
   $row=mysql_fetch_row($paging);
}
```

- If the function `shipping_list()` is in the same file as the rest of the code.*

You can not use `$paging` because you didn't return `$paging` you return only`$shipping` !

`$paging` is out of scope , only accessible within function `shipping_list()` .

```
 $row=mysql_fetch_row($paging);
```

shipping_list.php

```
function shipping_list(){
....
$paging = $MEMS -> query($query);
return $shipping;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Test it for yourself how the include, in the wrong spot, affects.

setHello.php

```
<?php
 function setHello() {
  echo "Hello World<br />";
 }
?>
```

testInclude.php

```
<?php
if (function_exists('setHello')) {
  print "setHello<br /> defined\n<br />";
} else {
  print "setHello<br /> not defined\n<br />";
} 

 setHello();
 include "SetHellop.php";

 if (function_exists('setHello')) {
  print "setHello<br /> defined\n<br />";
} else {
  print "setHello<br /> not defined\n<br />";
}

?>
```

You will get no error but only output :

```
setHello
not defined
```

change testInclude.php to

testInclude.php

```
<?php
if (function_exists('setHello')) {
  print "setHello<br /> defined\n<br />";
} else {
  print "setHello<br /> not defined\n<br />";
} 
 include "SetHellop.php"; 
 setHello();

 if (function_exists('setHello')) {
  print "setHello<br /> defined\n<br />";
} else {
  print "setHello<br /> not defined\n<br />";
}
?>
```

you get output .

```
setHello
not defined 
Hello World
setHello
defined
```

Comment: Still won't solve the issue, as `$paging` isn't in the scope of the `if`, only the scope of the included function.  Also, while it is good practice to include the file first, due to how PHP parses files, it isn't a requirement.  (Also, since that page includes a function that is `required` to continue with that function, it should be `require_once`'d instead of `include`'d.

Comment: @Jon : how to know the parser of the existence of `shipping_list();` if the php file has not been included at all. I assume the function `shipping_list();` is in the file `shipping_list.php` .

Comment: If the parser didn't recognize the existence of the function, PHP would fatally error trying to call the non-existent function rather than producing just an empty variable.  PHP works well within scopes so that it will parse the includes and requires that are within that scope prior to executing the first line of code.  That way all functions that are included are completely useable regardless of when included.  Again, you demonstrate best-practice, but not a solution to the question.

Comment: @Jon : Never heard about that . Test it ! . Look at my updated answer.